# Remove icons in gnome application menu

Tags: gnome3, icons, menu

How can you hide unwanted apps from the gnome app menu?

I've installed alacarte/main menu, unticked the apps but they still appear.

I've also checked in `/usr/share/applications` and viewed one the apps I don't want to appear and it says `NoDisplay=true` but still it shows.

Comment: Hi don, spot on with the `~/.local/share/applications` I found a few .desktop files in there. Also seems that it should be `Hidden=true` rather than `NoDisplay=true` which alacarte sets.

Comment: Tried both, neither works.

Answer (score 4):

According to the FreeDesktop documentation (https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html) the correct option is `NoDisplay=true` for what you want to achieve.

Try to create a copy of an existing file from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications` (with a different name so that you can easily identify it) and set both options to see the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The package `menulibre` provides the possibility to hide launchers with a simple switch:

[image: gnome menu hide launcher]

It's in french here, you'll find this option in your language

**Do not forget** to save your modifications with the following top-left icon:

[image: menu libre save]

Answer (score 0):

I am in Gnome 43.2 (Manjaro).

For example, the Main Menu app itself, corresponding to the command `alacarte`, is displayed in Activities, in the Accessories subpanel.

This would instantly and brutally eliminate Main Menu from Activities:

```
% sudo mv /usr/share/applications/alacarte.desktop /usr/share/applications/alacarte.desktop-moved
```

which would be instantly reversed by

```
% sudo mv /usr/share/applications/alacarte.desktop-moved /usr/share/applications/alacarte.desktop
```

Usually you only want to customize your session.  Even if you don't care about other users, you don't want your settings to be affected by operating system change (upgrade or switch to another Linux with Gnome).

As writen by [cesar-rickinho](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445459/335202), you can customize your session by copying `/usr/share/applications/alacarte.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications`.  Gnome will give priority to your file over root's file.

You can open Main Menu in Activities or in Terminal with the command `alacarte`, click Accessories, see [image: this].

Unticking Main Menu does nothing.  I think it is a bug.  But you can delete the item by clicking in the right column.  This will not actually delete the file but only write in it "Hidden=true".  Then, Main Menu is no more in Activities.

To restore the situation, you can delete "Hidden=true" directly in the file.  Main Menu reappears instantly in Main Menu and in Activities, though outside the Accessories subpanel, possibly another bug, so you also need to drag it back to Accessories.